# "User Interface" for macros in imagej

Tags: java, user-interface, plugins, macros, imagej

I created five macros which step by step effectively fulfill my research needs. I would like to join those macros in one effective plugin. All paths lead to java programming. But I was wondering, if there is a way, I could create “User interface” like that:

[image]

By clicking a button, macro would run. I would specify one or two variables (Insert year of the last ring…).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the `Dialog.*` macro functions. See the [DialogDemo macro](http://imagej.net/macros/DialogDemo.txt) for an example.

Comment: Your solution is very useful, but I am struggling with: 
1) I can not define "global" variables that would be automatically recognized by macros...
2) There is no »button« option (Dialog.addButton); I have to use dialog (Dialog.addChoices) and later runMacro…

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issues you are having without more detail, and/or you posting the code somewhere. From your original question, to join the macros, consider making each "macro" into a function that can be reused from multiple macros. For adding buttons to the dialog, I know you don't want to hear this, but consider writing a Java plugin instead. ImageJ 1.x's macro language is not designed to build extremely fancy dialogs (and adding an extra button to the dialog falls into that category).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dialog.create("Program");
Dialog.addChoice("Type:", newArray("A", "B","C"));
Dialog.show();
type = Dialog.getChoice();

if (type=="A"){
    runMacro("A");
} else {
    if(type=="B"){
        runMacro("B");
    } else {
        if (type=="C"){
        runMacro("C")
            }
        }
    }

////to start from the beginning
runMacro("Program")
```

So, as you can see, my little program is very straightforward. By choosing action, specific macro runs.

In my "macro A", specific variables have to be defined; such as: which year a tree was cut down

```
p = getNumber("The year of outmost ring?", 2020)
```

I would like to define those variables, BEFORE I choose action (using Dialog). It is just more userfriendly…

And I agree about Java programming; if I will want to seriously get in touch with some less-limited-software creating options…